# Why am I getting all the pizzas(relational algebra) and my joins messing up?

Tags: relation, relational-algebra

This is the database I am using for my queries

https://class.stanford.edu/c4x/DB/RA/asset/pizzadata.html

the syntax for writing out relational algebra queries is based off http://www.cs.duke.edu/~junyang/ra/ .

My query is to "Find all pizzas eaten by at least one female over the age of 20."
this is what I have so far

```
\project_{name,pizza}(
Person \join_{gender='female' and age>20} Eats
)
```

I think I have the right logic here.("\join_{cond} is the relational theta-join operator.") I also showed the name column for debugging purposes. I am joining two relations and only keeping the rows where gender is female and age is > 20.

The result of my query(against the correct query). I don't think this is a syntax issue. In the Eats relation, Fay only eats mushroom. I don't understand why she is paired with every pizza combination

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theta joins are cartesian; they join every row of each table with every row of every other table. In your example you are joining every row of `Person` where `gender='female' and age>20` with every row of `Eats`, regardless of `name`. You probably want:

```
Person \join_{gender='female' and age>20 and name=eater} \rename{eater, pizza} Eats
```

Note that Thetas typically increase the number of rows; you typically reduce the number of rows returned using Sigmas or selections. A more idiomatic way of performing your statement would be with a Select and natural join:

```
\select{gender='female' and age>20} Person \join Eats
```

Comment: Don't natural joins in general just join tables at the point where attributes are equal? Like since both these relations had name, that would the attribute chosen for the join?

Comment: So what I was doing wrong was that I only specified conditions for the first table?

Comment: Indeed natural joins do include only relations where identically-named attributes are equal. But you didn't use a natural join, you used a Theta join. I added an example using a natural join.

Comment: thank you!!. basically what happened was that my idea was right but I only applied to it to the first table, so those rows were combined with every possible combination of rows in the second table(I didn't specify anything)?

Comment: For the natural join, do you know of any other syntax besides Person.name or Eats.name? I get this error when I tried that, Error message: no such column: Eats.name

Comment: I probably use select anyways, thanks for all your help. I really appreciate it

Comment: I don't understand rename that well. I looked it up and found it to be relational rename operator. Does name refer to the name of eats or Person?

Comment: Rename changes the name of the columns returned by the following relation, so `\rename{eater, pizza} Eats` would change the name of the `name` column of `Eats` to `eater`. It is needed if you want to distinguish between identically-named columns. You would not need it in your example if you used a natural join, only if you use a Theta join. Please be aware that Theta joins and natural joins are different.

Comment: I get that theta joins are different  than natural joins. Theta joins - every possible combination

Comment: Because "Rename changes the name of the columns returned by the following relation". The following relation would be the join right? I now that the join will have two names. so how does the rename know which one to rename?

Comment: No, the “following relation” is the thing after the `\rename`, in the example it is the `Eats` table, not the join. The join precedes the `\rename`, it does not follow it. The join does not “have two names”; it joins `name=eater` because the first column of `Eats` is now called `eater`.

Comment: thanks. Do you also have to specify pizza in \rename{eater, pizza}? pizza is still the same name. Or do you have to do it to maintain consistency(the column names are now ....)

Comment: I don't know the RA software syntax. In traditional relational algebra you have to specify the name of every column. You should experiment with RA to find out how it handles unspecified columns.